# Can't get slick to work

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

This is the code

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-15">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>NET2GRID Support Portal</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/slick/slick.min.js"></script>


        </head>

        <body>

        <div class="slider">
            <div>
                <img src="/images/appliances/freezer.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="/images/appliances/electric_shower.png" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="/images/appliances/computer.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
                $('.slider').slick({});
        </script>
```

With this stylesheet:

```
.slider {
    width: 650px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

But this is the only thing I see on the page:

[image]

Am I using the slick carrousel correctly or am I using it wrong? I tried to follow the example in a jsfiddle but that doens't seem to work on my end.

Comment: What is the `{* *}` markup for? That's not standard HTML.

Comment: That means that it is commented out but i will update the code to not show those things

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: @K D no, no errors in the console

Comment: Have you tried removing the {}?   $('.slider').slick();

Comment: Yes i have, that doesn't change a thing